# Guess writer's native language

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a library or program that when given a text written in English tries to guess  the writer's native language (e.g. based on the usual mistakes, phrases, etc.) : ideally, it would give the likelihood for each language (e.g. 0.8 Spanish, 0.3 French, 0.2 Italian, etc.). If possible, free, open source, and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate or Ubuntu.

Comment: That sounds more like a computer-linguistic research idea, than like a software.  
You could use statistical methods if there are enough training texts available - like thousand of pages per person, and hundreds of persons per language.

Of course, it's a **good** computer-linguistic research idea!

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest thing I know to what you are after is an online quiz, not a program: http://www.gameswithwords.org/WhichEnglish/

But in terms of software, I recommend to try a supervised text categorization library (NLTK in Python, Mallet in Java), trained on texts for which you know native language of the author. I recommend to keep the stopwords and use n-grams as features to try capture specific characteristics of how a native speaker would talk in English.